# Passing Variables and Setting Form Attributes Based on Passed Variables in C#

Tags: c#, variables

I've been through at least a dozen articles on StackOverflow and I have found similar issues and tried to piece things together, but I just can't figure it out.

I'm making a Windows Form App in C#.
It has a small "Login" form where they enter an ID, and it verifies the ID is good, and then the main page comes up.

If I start with the Login page, I can create a new main page, and pass the id and name from the login to the main page when it's created.  The login is then hidden and the main page is shown.  However, when you close the main page the app doesn't close because the login is still open and hidden.  But if you close the login, it closes everything.

I think I need to start with the main page, and then create the login from the main page.  That way I can close the login once it's confirmed, and it won't close everything.  However, I can't figure out how to pass the ID and Name from the Login into the Main Page.

Here is what I have right now...
Program.cs

```
static void Main() {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Form_Login frmLogin = new Form_Login();
    if (frmLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        Application.Run(new Form_MainPage());
    } else {
        Application.Exit();
    }

}
```

Form_Login.cs

```
public partial class Form_Login : Form {
    public Form_Login() {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtBuyerID.Focus();
    }

    private void txtBuyerID_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
            string connString = "Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<database>;Integrated Security=true;";
            string BuyerName = "";
            string sql = "SELECT c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name AS name FROM contacts c WHERE c.buyer='Y' AND c.id=@BuyerID";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)) {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BuyerID", txtBuyerID.Text);
                try {
                    conn.Open();
                    BuyerName = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                    Form_MainPage frmMainPage = new Form_MainPage(txtBuyerID.Text,BuyerName);
                    this.txtBuyerID.Text = BuyerName;
                    Hide();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Form_MainPage.cs

```
public partial class Form_MainPage : Form {
        public Form_MainPage(string BuyerID, string BuyerName) {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Text = "BUYER: " + BuyerID + " - " + BuyerName;
            this.Show();
        }
    }
```

At this point I'm all mixed up and confused.  This was much easier when I did it way back in VB!  What do I need to change to get the correct sequence of loading and passing of variables from the Login to the MainPage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't be difficult to do. I think you want to pass `BuyerId` and `BuyerName` from the LoginPage to the MainPage upon successful authentication.

Form_Login.cs should look like this.

```
Form_MainPage frmMainPage = new Form_MainPage();
```

On your MainPage, create labels for `BuyerId` and `BuyerName`. Ensure they have public modifiers.

```
frmMainPage.BuyerId.Text="ID";
frmMainPage.BuyerName.Text="BuyerName";
frmMainPage.Show();
this.Close(); //or Hide();
```

See if that helps.

Comment: But if I add that to Form_Login.cs, when I close frmLogin, then it will close frmMainPage as well.

Comment: I see what you are saying about creating the labels.  Not sure how to have public modifiers though.  Still can't resolve how creating the frmMainPage from the Login won't close both with frmLogin is closed.

Comment: I suspect these lines in your program.cs file. `Form_Login frmLogin = new Form_Login(); if (frmLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) { Application.Run(new Form_MainPage()); } else { Application.Exit(); }` Try and replace with `Application.Run(new Form_Login());`

Comment: Just create labels normally and give them nice names. When you select a label, there should be an option to change the modifier in one of the properties. Should be set to `public` before they can be accessed from the LoginPage class.